# How can I use wildcard in the most efficient way?

Tags: php, mysql, search, wildcard

I have a quick search bar code that I'm working on and it looks like this:

searchbar.php:

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
<input type="text" name="search" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

search.php:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shop WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' OR id LIKE '%$search%' OR description LIKE '%$search%' OR keywords LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY id DESC ") or die(mysql_error());
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    $name = stripslashes($info['name']);
    $desc = stripslashes($info['description']);
    Print "<h3><a href=\"result.php?product=".$name."\">".$name."</a>: <font color=\"#cd0000\">".$desc."</font></h3><br>";
}
echo $name;
?>
```

result.php:

```
<?php
$result = $_GET['product'];
echo $result;
?>
```

Now my question is with the wildcard in my search.  Say somebody searches two words, "foo bar."  The way I have it the words have to be exactly in that order with a space between them for something to come up.  Is there a way so that within my search parameters if the words "foo" and "bar" are anywhere (even not next to each other) the result will show up?  Also I want it to work if the order of the words are reversed in order, "bar foo" (once again even not next to each other).

Comment: You can split the search term on space and include a new like clause for each word, but I doubt that is what people would expect. if I search for "give me" I wouldn't expect to get "American Lawgivers" as a result

Comment: I highly suggest you to do some little search on that topic first, because as you might imagine, you're not the first one concerned about that. The search here on site isn't that bad btw. and I remember the one or other Q&A material that handles this topic quite well and in different angles and different levels of detail.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing `LIKE '%...%'` matching, you should realize that MySQL can NOT use indexes to perform such searches and you'll be forcing a full table scan each time. And as you mention, you'd be searching for full phrases if a user enters `foo bar`.

You've got a few alternatives, using `foo bar` as the search phrase:

1) pre-process the search terms, so that each "word" in the search phrase becomes its own match set, e.g

```
WHERE (
        field1 LIKE '%foo%' OR field2 LIKE '%foo%' OR ...
     OR field1 LIKE '%bar%' OR field2 LIKE '%bar%' OR ...
)
```

2) switch to using a full-text index, reducing your query down to

```
WHERE MATCH(field1, field2, ...) AGAINST ('foo bar')
```

Comment: Okay so I used FULLTEXT and it's almost working. I created a FULLTEXT INDEX and made the columns in it name, description, and keywords.  I also ran the query in boolean mode because there are only two rows for this example so it's always in fault of the 50% rule.  My problem is that it returns results when I search for something in the "name" column but not the "description" or "keywords" column when they are both also in the fulltext index and the search query.  Any ideas what is causing that?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could eliminate spaces form your query using this

```
str_replace('  ' , '' , $string );
```

Here we are looking for spaces in first parameter , replacing it with nothing in second parameter , and loading the string which we wanna work on in third parameter..

HOPE this helps.

Comment: Okay this worked so if theres "foo blah blah blah bar" it will come up.  Do you know of a way to make it so it will show up in reversed order as well?

Comment: I assume you are asking to reverse the string eg : Hello -> olleH in this case you can use strrev() function .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for each individual item you have to search for them individually.
This piece of code (untested) should do

```
$search = explode(' ',$_POST['search']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM shop WHERE (";
foeach($search as $value){
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $whereClauses[] = "name LIKE '%$value%' OR id LIKE '%$value%' OR description LIKE '%$value%' OR keywords LIKE '%value%'";
}
$query.= implode(' OR ',$whereClauses) .') ORDER BY id DESC ';

$data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    $name = stripslashes($info['name']);
    $desc = stripslashes($info['description']);
    Print "<h3><a href=\"result.php?product=".$name."\">".$name."</a>: <font color=\"#cd0000\">".$desc."</font></h3><br>";
}
```

Note that this is a really bad approach as this will require a full table scan due to MySQL unable to use indexes due to the wildcards before and after the item to be found.

Comment: This code seems to make it so all results with "foo bar", "bar foo", "foo" and "bar" show up.  Is there a way so it only shows the results that have both "foo" and "bar"? not just one or the other

Comment: That is just a little more coding on the php part, to result with a clause like:
WHERE (name LIKE '%foo%bar%' OR name LIKE '%bar%foo%') OR
(id LIKE '%foo%bar%' OR id LIKE '%bar%foo%') OR
....